# Android: Check whether runtime permissions must be asked or not

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I would like to check whether a particular app need to handle Android Marshmallow runtime permissions in runtime or not.

Is it the following assumption correct?

```
/**
 * Checks whether runtime permissions must be handled or not.
 *
 * @param context Application context.
 * @return Handle runtime permissions or not.
 */
public static boolean shouldCheckRuntimePermissions(Context context) {
    return
            isApplicationWithMarshmallowTargetSdkVersion(context) &&
                    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
}

/**
 * Checks whether the app is compiled with targetSdkVersion Marshmallow or above.
 *
 * @param context Application context.
 * @return Application targetSdkVersion above 23 or not.
 */
public static boolean isApplicationWithMarshmallowTargetSdkVersion(Context context) {
    return
            context.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
}
```

Here is the table I have elaborated where for example `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permissions were needed to ask to the user with Android Marshmallow runtime permissions.

```
====================
target SDK |<23| 23|
====================
       |<23| X | X |
       ------------| 
OS SDK |23 | X | V |
====================
```

I know the existence of Support library [helpers](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), but I want to avoid them for this particular case.

Comment: I think you only need to check the build sdk version as the target version just indicates the sdk you were aiming while development.

Comment: @LuisMiguelSierra I don't think so, if you run an app with targetSDK 23 and OS SDK 22 you don't need to ask runtime permissions. At least this is what I've tested with the dangerous one COARSE_LOCATION.

Comment: Your assumption sounds good. Is it working all right?

Comment: @GoRoS Yep, you are right. Here it is explained the relation between targetSDK, buildSDK and runtime permissions. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @LuisMiguelSierra you're right, I've added an answer to help other people with the same problem/question. Thanks!

Comment: It makes sense to me if you think about Android supporting old apps that don't implement the runtime permisions. I just didnt think about. Upvoted and nice we have it clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@LuisMiguelSierra was right, I had the answer in the link I posted at the end of my question and I didn't realize at all. Here is the quote that answers my question and confirms my assumption and methods were right:

> On all versions of Android, your app needs to declare both the normal
>   and the dangerous permissions it needs in its app manifest, as
>   described in Declaring Permissions. However, the effect of that
>   declaration is different depending on the system version and your
>   app's target SDK level:
>
> - If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target    SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your
>     manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the
>     app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install 
>     the app at all.
> - If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and    your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the    permissions in
>     the manifest, and it must request each dangerous    permission it
>     needs while the app is running. The user can grant or    deny each
>     permission, and the app can continue to run with limited
>     capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.

So this assumption of when to ask permissions is confirmed:

```
====================
target SDK |<23| 23|
====================
       |<23| X | X |
       ------------| 
OS SDK |23 | X | V |
====================
```

Answer (score 1):

I your activity check if (the API version >= 23 and the permission is denied) then request the permission

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
}
```

And to get the result from the user just override

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION:
             if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Premission granted");
             }else {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Premission denied");
             }
             break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Abanoub, 1) I don't wanna know how to ask for runtime permissions as I posted 2) Read my last sentence where I say I don't wanna use support libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [EasyPermissions](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions) library from Google Samples. It handles the permission related checks and you don't need to worry about the checking the versions.

Comment: Hi jaibatrik, thanks for the answer. I already knew about this sample but I simply want to understand the logic of "when to ask", not "how to ask" and if my assumption is right or not.

Comment: If SDK version is less than M, you need not check for permission, just declare it in Manifest. If it is equal or greater than M, check for permission using `Context#checkPermission`. If permission is not there, ask for permission.