# Android app getting killed (not crashing) in doze mode on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have this app, it does location tracking. I am using an AlarmManager which invokes a service every 5 minutes. The service takes the current location using the LocationManager, uploads it and stops itself.

App was working fine till Android Lollipop. But on Marshmallow it is getting killed by OS (not crashing) after 3 or 4 hours.

I did white-list my app. I did make it an admin app, but still it's getting killed by the OS.

Any help?

Comment: Have you grant permission at run time in Marshmallow

Comment: No but my targetSDK is 16. so i dont think i need to ask runtime permission.

Comment: No, you have to ask for Runtime Permission if you are targeting API > 23. just look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484110/7073808). if you want to know how to ask for RUntime permission in android then you can look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44650453/7073808)

Comment: I am not targeting API >= 23

Comment: but your app is running on API 23 (Marshmallow)

Comment: ok let me add runtime persmissions then .